# Floating action button now visible

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

I have a support map fragment that is shown in an activity. However, the floating action button is not visible. I have tried so many ways but I am not getting anywhere.

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context=".views.activities.MainActivity"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_current_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_white_24dp"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

```
val fragmentTransaction = mainAct.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val mapFragment = mainAct.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, mapFragment)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Map Fragment")
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this.mainAct)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT:** In the end what worked for me was

```
val mapFragment = this.childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
```

Comment: Please try to use RelativeLayout instead of frameLayout because FAB is lying under the fragment...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This did not work for me.

Comment: Are there two children in the FrameLayout?

Comment: Nope that's my fragment layout file with closing tag at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add the fragment twice, once from xml then again in code. Just remove the code for the fragment transaction and instead use findFragmentById to find and update the fragment.

```
val mapFragment = mainAct.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this.mainAct)
```

Or if you want to do it in code just replace the fragment in xml with a frameLayout call it fragment_container and add the new fragment like this

```
val mapFragment = SupportMapFragment() // use the apropriate constructor
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mapFragment)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried your solution for some reason, the floating action button does not show up. I assume it's under the layout. So I had to use a child fragment manager to have a fragment inside the fragment.